# How does one expand an expression within a Gamma function?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, expression-manipulation

I'd like to convert expressions such as

```
Gamma[(1/10)*(13 + 10*n)]
```

to

```
Gamma[13/10 + n]
```

I tried the rule

```
Gamma[r_] -> Gamma[Expand[r]]
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You want `:>` instead of `->`. Alternatively just use `ExpandAll` on the complete expression.

Comment: FullSimplify@Gamma[(1/10)*(13 + 10*n)] works as well.

Comment: An alternative is to use `FunctionExpand@ Gamma[(1/10)*(13 + 10*n)]`

Comment: ExpandAll     also works.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [`ExpandAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpandAll.html):

```
ExpandAll[Gamma[(1/10)*(13 + 10*n)]]
(*  Gamma[13/10 + n]  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a delayed version of the rule

```
Gamma[r_]:>Gamma[Expand[r]]
```

rather than

```
Gamma[r_]->Gamma[Expand[r]]
```

otherwise the `Expand` is applied to `r` (returning simply `r`) before the substitution is attempted.

A slightly briefer alternative is

```
r_Gamma :> Expand/@r
```

This matches any expression that has `Head` `Gamma` and has the added effect of matching multiple argument versions of `Gamma` and expanding each of their arguments independently.